# paper-dialog not opening on click of an button

Tags: dialog, polymer

Higuys,

as per the polymer documentation on paper dialog i did this

```
<paper-card elevation=3 align="center" id="question-ask-card">

      <h1 id="got-a-question">
          Got a question ?
      </h1>

    <paper-button data-dialog="Qdialog" id="askit" raised ><p id="ask-it">Write on Blackboard</p></paper-button>

</paper-card>
```

and the dialog is

```
  <paper-dialog id="Qdialog">

    <h1>sdjafadsfasdfjhg</h1>

    <p>
      aouaouwghsefjgzskdcghizbskk
    </p>

 </paper-dialog>
```

So how to link that dialog on click of that button,please help me!!!!!!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have included the paper-dialog on your page? (`<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-dialog//paper-dialog.html">`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is just sitting in the main document, this can be as easy as adding `onclick="Qdialog.open()"` to your button.

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Polymer Example">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="http://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="paper-elements/paper-elements.html" rel="import">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <paper-card elevation=3 align="center" id="question-ask-card">
    <h1 id="got-a-question">Got a question ?</h1>
    <paper-button data-dialog="Qdialog" id="askit" raised onclick="Qdialog.open()"><p id="ask-it">Write on Blackboard</p></paper-button>
  </paper-card>
  <paper-dialog id="Qdialog">
    <h1>sdjafadsfasdfjhg</h1>
    <p>
      aouaouwghsefjgzskdcghizbskk
    </p>
  </paper-dialog>
</body>
```